# Spring Boot CORS configuration not allowing methods

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-boot

I am attempting to login through a Node development server, to a REST endpoint on a Spring Boot application. Both are running HTTPS.

I can cURL the spring boot application on :8444 and get a valid JWT back if the credentials are correct.

However, when attempting to authenticate through the web application, it will not work.

Namely, I can see the response headers from the Spring Boot application are wrong.

My CORS config:

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() { // Enables CORS globally
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/api/**")
                    .allowedOrigins("https://localhost:8443")
                    .allowCredentials(true)
                    .allowedMethods("PUSH", "OPTIONS");
        }
    };
}
```

However, PUSH and OPTIONS are not present in the response header when calling from the frontend:[image]

Why are they under "ALLOW"? How do I set "allowedMethods" to be "Access-Control-Allow-Methods"?

```
WebSecurity http config:

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/api/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
```

After changing websecurity to the above, i once again get a 403:

[image]

Comment: The `/api/login` return http status code `403`, has it been intercepted by spring-security?

Comment: This is weird. I get a HTTP 200 if I add `@CrossOrigin(origins = "https://localhost:8443", maxAge = 3600)` to the REST controller ... but should this not be configured already PÅ